# IMPORTXML Google Sheets for every 2nd node?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble trying to get a value with IMPORTXML in a google spreadsheet ...

I am using as xpath:

`//*[contains(@class,"price")` which returns me smoothly, ALL prices posted on a web page

The problem is that within that same class (and I don't know why, with dynamic ID's!) I have 2 nodes/prices: "Registered Customer Price" and "Non-Customer Price", which is the 2nd. value ... and the one I am interested in obtaining.

So, I wanted to apply it like this:

`(//*[contains(@class,"price")])[2]` and with this, I only get the 2nd price... but of the whole page!
(and not the 2nd. price of each and every item!)

I assume it is a "syntax" problem ... but no matter how many times I try it, I don't get the expected result!

Can you give me a hand with this?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi player0, thank you for your attention!
Here you can access a sample, with the real data I want to get:

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rOy_ePSOWst_hfjXbXQzHZHXDW2h3hSg3pI3R3odMWA/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use :

```
//div[@class='price-box'][2]//span[@id]
```

Output :

[image: Prices]

EDIT : With IMPORTFROMWEB:

```
//h4[.="Precio unitario por unidad"]/following-sibling::span/span[@id]
```

[image: IMPFRWEB]

EDIT 2 : More robust XPath :

```
//h4[.="Precio unitario por unidad"]/following-sibling::span[@class="price-excluding-tax"][count(following-sibling::*)=0]/span[@id]
```

[image: Fix]

Comment: At this point, I think I made the mistake of assuming that things would be the same, usin a solution in other context, but it seems NOT. - I should have started the topic from that side... so as not to waste your time!! MY FAULT!

Dear E.Wiest, even though your suggestion is PERFECT and works OK when entering the XPath that way, for a "stand-alone" IMPORTXML... now I find that it is not, when trying to use it with the IMPORTFROMWEB addon!

Is there any chance that you understand WHY?

Comment: I have updated the sample sheet, to show you how it works with your sugested Xpath (that works fine in a stand-alone IMPORTXML)... but applied trough the IMPORTFROMWEB Addon!
Please kindly check it: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rOy_ePSOWst_hfjXbXQzHZHXDW2h3hSg3pI3R3odMWA/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer. The addon seems a bit off when you use a position in a predicate ([1],[2],...). So avoid to use this in your XPath expression. Also, thanks for sharing "IMPORTFROMWEB" addon. Never heard of it before but a very nice tool.

Comment: Awesomeeee!! E.Wiest, you're a genius, man! You saved my potatoes! hehehe
That way, it WORKS WONDERFUL and does exactly what is expected.
I don't have enough words to thank you...
SOLVED  =)

Comment: OK. Post is edited with a solution. For the product with 4 prices, the value is taken from the 2nd div ("Precio unitario por unidad") like all the other products.

Comment: Don't know what I did... but I just deleted my previous comment! =(


Anyway, I got your solution to my question... and I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help.
You're the man! hehehe


THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: By the way... can you recommend me some resources, where I can learn something about this? I just made a copy/paste of what you told me... and honestly, I would like to UNDERSTAND, what I am doing and how it works!

Comment: Start from here : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp and practice as much as you can. Feel free to mark your answer as solved.

Comment: I could not find a way to mark as "solved"??...  Where is the option?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTXML(
 "http://www.maxiconsumo.com/sucursal_villa_dominico/comestibles/aceites/aceite-girasol.html";
 "//*[contains(@id,'price-including-tax')]"); MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(IMPORTXML(
 "http://www.maxiconsumo.com/sucursal_villa_dominico/comestibles/aceites/aceite-girasol.html";
 "//*[contains(@id,'price-including-tax')]")))); 2)=0)
```

Comment: It's ok. As I described it, the result would be as expected... however (although it may be a fault on my part), I need the values to arrive "pure" on the sheet. since my future intention is to use it with the IMPORTFROMWEB addon (which allows the scrapping of several URLs simultaneously) and it doesn't support a formula... that's why I wanted to get it (and insisted so much) from the XPATH itself ...
No way to tell it (in the XPATH) to return only the second node found?
Really thanks for your help!